# What is the best WordPress plugin for Amazon s3 backups?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, backup

I tried  Automatic WordPress Backup and WordPressWPup on my Dreamhost server and both of them failed to backup blog content to Amazon s3. Is there any other free plugin to backup an entire blog to Amazon s3?

Comment: I don't think there is one currently. I may be developing one at work in the next month or so. Which may get open sourced onto WordPress.org

Comment: That's great. lets us know once you develop the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I am using [Automatic WordPress Backup](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/automatic-wordpress-backup/) and it works well.

It let's you schedule it and it takes both the database and the filesystem.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Gopinath What was the error/failure?  I'm using Automatic WordPress Backup on Dreamhost without issues.

Answer (score 2):

BackupBuddy works flawlessly for backing up to AmazonS3. FYI: it is a commercial Plugin, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HotBackup](http://codecanyon.net/item/hot-backup-manager/1910588?ref=straightforward) plugin. It will create database + file system backup and upload it to Amazon S3. The plugin works automatically, so you don't need to worry about it, everything will be made for you. Plus it can restore backups.