# What is the most comprehensive backup plugin for WordPress (it does not have to be free)?

Tags: multisite, backup

[Related to this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8554/what-is-the-best-wordpress-plugin-for-amazon-s3-backups/10603#10603)

I am currently using Automatic WP backup.  It works ok.  Now I am looking for something more comprehensive and granular.  A plugin that let's me choose the sites to backup inside my network, the type of content, the granularity on restores. ETC.

Examples of things that I will like to do:

- Schedule a backup, with notification to owners (site owners)
- Verification of the backup (that it will work once I need it).
- That I can change variables important to restore in different webhost

Comment: I am not sure (between question's title and description) - are you looking for maximum backup scope (_comprehensive_) or maximum flexibility (_granular_)? These  do not necessarily go together.

Comment: You are right, I guess I am looking for both, but if I can't have both, then comprehensive.  I will update the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you guys haven't mentioned it yet then i'll have to

[**BackWPup**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/backwpup/) a free site and database backup plugin packed with features and easy to configure

- Database Backup
- WordPress XML Export
- Optimize Database
- Check\Repair Database
- File Backup
- Backups in zip,tar,tar.gz,tar.bz2
  format
- Store backup to Folder
- Store backup to FTP Server
- Store backup to Amazon S3
- Store backup to RackSpaceCloud
- Store backup to DropBox
- Send Log/Backup by eMail

when ever i have a client that is a bit too cheap on hosting and a propper backup server i just set him up with a dropbox account and this plugin creates and uploads the backup there, and if the plugin runs into trubles it sends the admin a log by mail.
i defintly recommend this as a free solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet found a single backup solution which provides what I need for both database and file backup. So far I have used the following: VaultPress, ManageWP, BackupBuddy, SyncBackSE, and WordPress Database Backup.

Notes on what I have found below...

**VaultPress:** $15 per month per blog. Backs up continuously, but does not give you a single browseable backup archive that you can easily dig through with a folder directory listing. To me, this makes it cumbersome to retrieve a file from backup. For me, this solution is too expensive since I need to backup seven blogs.

**ManageWP:** Somewhere around $20 per month, but this also gives you a boatload of centralized mangement features and ability to backup/manage 10 blogs. Unfortunately I was not able to get this to work with Dropbox for my file backups (see notes on BackupBuddy below for possible reasons).

**BackupBuddy:** $100 per year (for 10 blogs). Works great in all sorts of ways, and worked great for me with Amazon S3, but due to a combination of limits in the Dropbox API and my shared hosting provider's PHP memory, it does not seem possible to get a backup working for more than 30MB of files.

**SyncBackSE together with WordPress Database Backup plugin:** This is my best solution overall, but it requires a desktop computer at home to be powered-on for nightly backups. SyncBackSE is a desktop app for Windows that costs about $30 one-time. This is set to backup any changed files each night via FTP. You have full control over what files are backed up and notification options. The files come down to my desktop and get further backed up as part of my Dropbox plan. No recurring costs other than Dropbox, which I had anyway. Then to handle the database backup I use WordPress Database Backup. Since I was not too happy with the requirement to have a powered-on computer I have been trying to replace this with BackupBuddy but as noted above various limitations are preventing a full switch to BackupBuddy.

If you can deal with some of the manual work involved in SyncBackSE, I think it is a pretty robust solution (when combined with a database backup plugin of your choice).

Answer (score 0):

Hi **@Geo:**

Probably [**VaultPress**](http://vaultpress.com/).  If that's too expensive, try [**BackupBuddy**](http://pluginbuddy.com/purchase/backupbuddy/). Those are the ones I've heard the most positive feedback about.

Comment: Note the use of the tern Network. Vaultpress doesn't support it, and backupbuddy does the whole network. not just one blog. (also they don't check for super admis, so users can backup the entire network too. joy.)

you'll be stuck backup up everything,. Granular restoration of a specific table should be done (IMO) right in the db and very rarely. It's a pain in the arse if you have one client hosing their posts regularly. you charge those guys extra. ;)

Comment: @andrea_r - Thanks for the comments and helping me gain from your experience. Would love to see you answer this question too as it sounds like you've got some great insight. I'm curious; do you think VaultPress will offer support for networks soon?

Answer (score 0):

I use [Vaultpress](http://vaultpress.com/) and works great. And the price includes the storage cost, while most other solutions, like [Automatic Backup](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/automatic-wordpress-backup/) requiere you to have an FTP or S3 accounts and pay for them.

Also worth mentioning that Vaultpress is continuous backup, and that you can download at anytime parts of the backup. For instance, the other day I edited my theme and made a mistake. Went to my Vaultpress account, downloaded only the themes backup files from one hour before and replaced the theme files with the backup ones. All took me about 10 mins. Fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative I can suggest [HotBackup](http://codecanyon.net/item/hot-backup-manager/1910588?ref=straightforward) plugin which can:

1. create backups by schedule;
2. send notifications;
3. uploads backups to Dropbox, Amazon S3, remote FTP;
4. restore backups with url fixing.